# How can i close window and relaod in asp.net

Tags: sql, asp.net, aspxgridview

My code look like below.

```
protected void btnApprove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (id == "Button2")
    {
        string sql = @"update AdjTranSeqDetails set Approver1Status = 'Rejected',finalStatus='Rejected' ,updatedtime = GETDATE(),Approver1Comment ='{1}',modifieduser = '{2}' where TranSeq ={0}";
        sql = String.Format(sql, tbxTranSeq.Text, TextBox2.Text, Master.CurrentUser);
        string sql2 = @"INSERT INTO AdjTranSeqDetailsHistory SELECT * FROM AdjTranSeqDetails WHERE tranSeq={0}";
        sql2 = String.Format(sql2, tbxTranSeq.Text);
        string sql3 = @"delete from AdjTranSeqDetails where tranSeq={0}";
        sql3 = String.Format(sql3, tbxTranSeq.Text);
        if (dba.SqlUpdate(sql, ref ex, ref rowCt) || dba.SqlInsert(sql2, ref ex, ref rowCt) ||dba.SqlDelete(sql3, ref ex, ref rowCt))
        {
            string sscript = "<script language=\"Jscript\" > ";
            if (Master.PageMode == "View")
            {
                sscript += "if (window.opener && !window.opener.closed) ";
                sscript += "{window.opener.DoSearch();}";
            }
            sscript += "window.opener='x';self.close();";
            sscript += "</Script>";
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "SelfClose", sscript);

        }
    }
    updateapp();
    GetBillTranInfo();
}
```

Like Button2, like have 10 button. If one if condition function done I need to close the window and need to reload the page. Can I do like this?

I have tried like above but that is not working for me.

Answer (score 1):

In my user controls, after updating data I do:

```
Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
```

That ensures that the page is reloaded, and it works fine from a user control. You use `RawURL` and not `Request.Url.AbsoluteUri` to preserve any GET parameters that may be included in the request.

You probably don't want to use: `__doPostBack`, since many aspx pages behave differently when doing a postback.